# How to enroll zero touch

Tags: android, emm, android-device-owner

Hi I'm working on the EMM Android application and I need to add factory reset protection I have done this by doing https://developers.google.com/android/work/play/emm-api/prov-devices#create_a_qr_code
using the device owner profile but now the issue is if the user does hard reset then it will be removed device owner and I lost the control over the device for this I find the solution to enroll the device with google zero-touch enrollment but it's confusing. Does anyone have steps on how to implement it because it requires a reseller are mandatory or we can enroll without a reseller?

Thank you!

I have already tried this workout https://support.google.com/work/android/answer/7514005?hl=en but as I told you it required a reseller.

Comment: At that point you're worrying about the wrong thing.  You have a device that's in someone else's control (hence they're able to do a hardware reset).  They could just as easily open the device, pop out the flash storage, and replace it and have the same effect.  What security issue are you actually trying to solve here?  Because the only one you could be trying to solve is theft, and even if you manage this it won't work (see above problem).

Comment: what I want: The device belongs to an organization so the thing is employer can't do a hard reset if he is doing a hard reset then the device must be activated as an organization-controlled device.

Comment: And what are you trying to accomplish by that?  If it's to protect against device theft, it won't help, as described above.  And there's nothing else that it protects against.  And if you really want to do that, your best way is to use a custom AOSP image that hardcodes the device owner in the firmware.